# How to determine when USB flash drives (or SD cards) are or are not appropriate for a task that involves write operations?

Tags: usb, ssd, usb-flash-drive, sd-card, continuous-operation

How does one determine when USB flash drives (or SD cards) *are* or *are not* appropriate for a task that involves multiple write operations?

One example of such a task would be to use to manage photographs.  This would require initial writes, plus writes every time you decide photos should be moved to a different folder to categorize them.  Plus, if you want to crop a bunch of photos, add watermarks, or perform other edits that would require additional write operations.  At some point, a flash drive just can't handle too much writing, but how does one determine if a use like this is appropriate?

If money grew on trees, the obvious answer would be to always use an SSD instead of a flash drive.  But money doesn't grow on trees, and often USB flash drives are more economical.  Plus, many of us have a bunch of USB drives or SD cards laying around.

But since USB flash drives (and SD cards) have lower limits to the amount of available write cycles, what is an effective technique to determine if a USB flash drive is suitable for a particular use case?

Related: [What actually happens with an USB flash drive when it dies?](https://superuser.com/questions/175524/what-actually-happens-with-an-usb-flash-drive-when-it-dies)

Comment: Basically it would boil down to buying a whole bunch of them and testing them to destruction. Alternatively using Google and searching for "[this usb drive] review" or "[this usb drive] benchmark" and seeing if you get lucky.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for your comment,  Based on what you wrote, I think I need to reword my question a little.  I'm wondering about appropriate uses of USB drives in general, but you thought I meant specific devices.  After reading your comment, I see how what I wrote could definitely be construed that way, and so I shall edit... :)

Comment: @Mokubai Okay, I made some substantial edits.  I hope I did a good job making my question more clear.

Comment: Moving a file between folders on the same drive just changes the entry in the file-system, hence this just writes up to a few KB. Regarding the question if a drive is suitable - read reviews. I prefer tests of offline tech magazines as finding good and reliable and comparable tests online can be difficult.

Comment: @Robert Good point about moving files between folders, although I do have to wonder why moving files within the same partition is often such a slow procedure (especially on Android).  Even if the data isn't actually moved, the MFT/FAT/etc has to be written to, and unless the OS is smart enough to keep moving those structures to different locations on the drive (which I don't think most are), would those physical blocks get repeated wear during file move operations?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Android is a special case as non-rooted apps don't have direct file-system access anymore on the SD-card and since Android 10 also on the internal section called "/sdcard". And the API apps have to use as far as I know has no "move file" command, therefore apps have to copy the data of a file and then delete the original file.

Comment: @Robert Thanks so much.  That would certainly explain why file move operations are so painfully slow on Android!  Any thoughts on the second half of my last comment?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket SSDs don't do data deduplication, hence they don't check the content to be saved. Therefore a simulated move by copy+delete actually writes all data blocks of the file again and thus decreases maximum life-time of the flash chips.